# Alternative proof for $\forall n\in\mathbb N (n\ge 6 \Rightarrow \exists a,b\in\mathbb N : n=3a+4b)$

Tags: induction, alternative-proof

Can I use only strong induction in order to prove
$$\forall n\in\mathbb N (n\ge 6 \Rightarrow \exists a,b\in\mathbb N : n=3a+4b)$$
Is there any other option?

Comment: The title isn't supposed to replace the first line of your question.

Comment: Does it work for n=9 ?

Comment: Is $0\in\mathbb N$ for you? Because else the proposition is false.

Comment: Yea, I just realized that OP is using $N$ with 0 included. Else, it doesn't even for 6 or 8 or 9.

Comment: (0∈N) yea.@AlexR

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to discuss the below three cases (below, k ∈N and 1<=k)

1. $n=3k = 3*a$
2. $n=3k+1 = 3*(k-1) + 4 = 3*a + 4*1$
3. $n=3k+2 = 3*(k-2) + 8 = 3*(k-2) + 8 = 3*a + 4*2$

Comment: In the cases 2,3 one needs $k-1$ respectively $k-2$ to be nonnegative. Of course that may be made clear if $n\ge 6$... [just noticed you already said $k\ge 1$]

Answer (score 1):

if $n=3a+4b$ then $n+12k$ is also expressible in this form, so it suffices to show the proposition is true for $n \in [6,17]$

Answer (score 1):

We show that "usual" induction, i.e. going from $n$ to $n+1$, can be made to work here. Assume that $n \ge 6$ and we have a representation $n=3a+4b.$ Then either $a>0$ or not. If $a>0$ we can use one fewer $3$ and one more $4$ and arrive at $n+1.$ On the other hand if $a=0$ we have $n$ as all 4's, and there are at least two 4's involved since $n \ge 6.$ In this case we may decrease by two 4's and increase by three 3's and arrive at $n+1.$

Answer (score 1):

More generally,
if
$n = pa+qb$
for positive
$a, b, p, q$,
then
$n+2pq
=p(a+q)+q(b+p)
$.

Therefore,
if $n$ can be represented
in the form
$pa+qb$
for $2pq$
consecutive values of $n$,
it can be represented
in that form
for all larger
values of $n$.