# Prove the following by induction: Every natural number n > 6 can be written as n = 3j + 4k for some integers j and k

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I have tried solving this question but haven't been able to. Pls if anyone could provide any other views so I could crack it it would be greatly appreciated

This was my attempt at solving the question: For n = 7, we can write 7 as 3(1) + 4(1) since both j and k are integers (j = 1, k = 1).

Inductive Step: Assume that for some arbitrary positive integer m > 6, we can write m = 3j + 4k for some integers j and k.

Now, I want to show that this implies the statement for m + 1.

Starting with the assumed statement for m: m=3j+4k

Adding 1 to both sides: m+1=3j+4k+1

Now, we can express m+1 as 3(j+1)+4(k−1).

Since j and k are integers, (j+1) and (k−1) are also integers.

Comment: Looks like you have swapped the roles of $+1$ and $-1$. Otherwise, in what sense do you say that you have not solved the problem?

Comment: (I also wonder if you are supposed to only consider nonnegative integers $j, k$).

Comment: Presumably, you mean "positive integers $j,k,$" or "non-negative integers $j,k.$"

Comment: Otherwise, $3(-n)+4n=n$ for all $n,$ even $n\leq 6.$

Comment: Does this provide any other views? [Alternative proof for $\forall n\in\mathbb N (n\ge 6 \Rightarrow \exists a,b\in\mathbb N : n=3a+4b)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1015116/89922)

Comment: It appears that in the statement "Now, we can express m+1 as 3(j+1)+4(k−1)" the signs of +1 and -1 are interchanged.